# Copy node and alter its content

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I'm kinda stuck on a transformation i'd like to make on a xml file.

Basically i'm trying to copy all the xml but change some tags which only begins like this

XML code :

```
<test alt="foo" title="bar"/>
```

What i'd like to get after passing the xsl :

```
<test alt="foo"/>
```

Or

```
<change alt="foo" title=""/>
```

Thing is, sometimes i got tag with a lot of attributes, so i dont want to make a template match and then change every attributes manually.

Actually i'm doing this :

```
<xsl:template match="test">
    <change><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></change>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="test/@title">
    <xsl:attribute name="title">
        <xsl:value-of select=""/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

But it doesnt change the content of title in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all such tasks you should start with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and then add templates for nodes that need special treatment, for instance

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="test/@title"/>
```

would copy everything unchanged but would delete all `title` attributes of `test` elements.

Or

```
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="test">
    <change><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></change>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="test/@title">
    <xsl:attribute name="title"/>
</xsl:template>
```

should implement your second requirement. If you still have problems then post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks it did the trick ! Now let's say i got an xhtml file, so i got the <html> surrounding the rest of my tags. Which path should i use to  make the same thing as <xsl:template match="test/@title"/> ? (html/test/@title does not seems to work)

Comment: Well the nice thing about match patterns is that you don't need to specify a full path in most cases as e.g. `match="test/@title"` will handle all `title` attributes of all `test` elements, independent on any ancestors the `test` might have. If you want to restrict the treatment you can use e.g. `match="body/div[@class = 'foo']/test/@title"` to handle only the `title` attributes of `test` elements in those `div` elements with `class` being `foo` that are direct children of the `body` element. And of course XHTML normally has a namespace which always complicates things with XPath.

Comment: You would better ask a new question with an X(HT)ML sample showing any namespaces if you continue to have problems with XHTML input.

Comment: Thanks again, if i get any more problems that's what i'll do

Answer (score 0):

To remove any attributes save for `alt`, use an identity transform with an exception:

**Stylesheet (remove other attributes)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
          <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
          </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*[name() != 'alt']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test alt="foo"/>
```

---

Or else, to set the value of all attributes except that of `alt` to `""`, use:

**Stylesheet (make other attributes empty)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
          <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
          </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="test">
        <change>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </change>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*[name() != 'alt']">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<change alt="foo" title=""/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but Martin's answer suit best my needs as it specify the change for one tag, unless @*[name() != 'alt'] which would set all tag except alt to ""